How can I permanently remove file/folder from svn (using TortoiseSvn)?
My repository is becoming very large and I want to delete some stuff.
I went on Tortoise Repository Browser and deleted everything I didn't need.
This didn't work as Tortoise kept the previous versions like it was just a normal commit...
Is there a way to permanently remove a folder and its linked history?
I can't find the answer I need about this...
Another thing I could do is create a new repository and the folder I still want to use in there but I'd lose my commit history on those files...
